# Django Queryset order_by annotate Count on related model

Tags: django, django-queryset

Let's say I have some pages, and the view to display one is `PageDetail`, and to display all is `PageList`.

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ....
```

And I keep track of how many times a page is read:

```
class PageView(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    session = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ....
```

Every time `PageDetail` view is called from a unique session per day, I create a new `PageView` object.
That's a basic hit counter.

Now in `PageList` I would like to show the most popular pages first. I can do an `annotate` and `select_related` to get a list of `PageView`, e.g.:

```
 views = PageView.objects.all().values('page__title').annotate(count = Count('page')).order_by('-count').prefetch_related('page')
```

but I want a queryset of `Page`s, not a list of `PageView`s.

What have I missed?